# Sorting alpha-numerical values

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort images based on numbers in the file Name.

For example:
[1.jpg, 10.jpg, 3.jpg... ]

I tired natsort library and sorted function the both give the same result

```
import glob 
from natsort import natsorted
images =[]
for img in glob.glob('E:/train/image/*.jpg'):
    images.append(img)
    natsorted(images)
```

it Outputs: 
[**1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 22, 3**]

but it must be:
[**1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 22**]

Comment: You've asked for a naturally-sorted copy of the contents of `images`, and then thrown it in the trash.

Comment: How about accepting and upvoting the best answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do the following:

```
import glob 
from natsort import natsorted
images = natsorted(glob.glob('E:/train/image/*.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`natsorted` is not an in-place sort. It returns a new sorted list so you must assign it to a variable.
This should work:

```
import glob 
from natsort import natsorted
images =[]
for img in glob.glob('E:/train/image/*.jpg'):
    images.append(img)
images = natsorted(images)
```